# When to use the verb "cercare" and when to use the verb "guardare"?

Tags: verbs

The meanings of both words is the same meaning "look" if I am not wrong. Then what are the correct contexts of these Italian verbs: *cercare* e *guardare*?
Please explain with examples.

Answer (score 9):

You are mistaken in the meaning. The verb *guardare* means *to look at, to observe*, while the verb *cercare* means *to look for, to search*.

*Look* in English can have many different meanings, depending on the preposition following it and you have to account for it while translating.